# Can $ x^2+\frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}=3 $ be solved by 'completing square method'?

Tags: quadratics, quartics

On using the quartic formula, there are two zeroes of this equation

$$
x^2+\frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}=3
$$

So, I was wondering if this equation could be solved like a quadratic equation.

Is it possible. If yes, how?

Comment: Do you mean $x^2 + \frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2} = 3$?

Comment: Yes. Actually, I dont know to use LaTex.

Comment: Then I suggest you take a look at [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Can you show us how you solved it using quadratic formula.

Comment: 'Quartic' not 'Quadratic' formula.

Comment: Well you can show that the substitution $x=at+b$ will never turn this to a "quadratic friendly" polynomial in $t$ (only powers of $0$, $2$ and $4$), so at least that is not a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may notice that the golden ratio $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is a solution of the given equation, since $\varphi^2=\varphi+1$ implies
$$ \varphi^2+\frac{\varphi^2}{(\varphi+1)^2} = \varphi^2+\varphi^{-2} = L_2 = 3. $$
In particular, the algebraic conjugate of $\varphi$, given by $\bar{\varphi}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, is also a solution of the given equation, and the polynomial $x^2-x-1$ (i.e. the minimal polynomial of $\varphi$) is a divisor of
$$ x^2(x+1)^2+x^2-3(x+1)^2.$$
By performing a polynomial division, we get that the other solutions are given by $x^2+3x+3=0$, i.e. by $x=\frac{-3\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $
x^2+\frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}=3
$ as
$$x^2(x+1)^2+x^2=3(x+1)^2$$
or
$$x^2(x+1)^2+2x(x+1)+1= 4(x+1)^2$$
which allows the completion of square
$$[x(x+1)+1]^2=[2(x+1)]^2$$
Then, factorize with $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$
$$(x^2-x-1)(x^2+3x+3)=0$$